# Set permission to "Can review" on Word Document being shared on OneDrive programmatically

Tags: c#, onedrive

In Word, you can select Share, and then set permissions to View, edit or review. I want to share Word documents with Can Review permissions programmatically. I have found information on how to share documents on Onedrive for Business programmatically and set permission to allow editing or not. However, I haven't found a way of setting permission to review programmatically. How can I do this? Need to do it from a C# client application.

This is the feature I am talking about?

https://m365admin.handsontek.net/onedrivesharepoint-review-mode-for-word-documents/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no "Can review" permission in the current permission level. You could create a custom permission in permission levels. Then you can use following code to grant user custom permission

```
RoleDefinitionBindingCollection rd = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx);  
rd.Add(ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("custom permission"));  
Principal user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser("Domain\\ID12345");  
item.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);  
item.RoleAssignments.Add(user, rd);  
item.Update();  
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: How can I restrict what a user can do in a Word Add-in based on this custom permission? There is a 'Can review' permission when you share on sharepoint from within Word.